# simple UDP server, error: int cannot be converted to String in BlueJ

Tags: java, sockets, parsing, server, port

I'm a beginner at java and trying out a simple sever client that's supposed to connect to a socket and send a string message. (I'm using BlueJ) When I try to run it, I enter the port a number and it tells me "Error: incompatible types: int cannot be converted to java.lang.String[]". I'm confused as I'm trying to do a reverse, string to int. Here's my code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
public class HelloServer
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String msg="words of a message";
            try
            {
                byte [] data = msg.getBytes();
                int port = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
                InetAddress address = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
                DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket(port, address);
                DatagramPacket request = new DatagramPacket(data, data.length,address, port);
                socket.send(request);
                System.out.println(data);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {System.out.println(e);} 
    }
}
```

P.S. It compiles but there may be mistakes I'm not aware of, also it's a part of my uni work and I have to pass the port number, so I can't just specify it as a variable. 
I suspect it's something very simple but I can't figure it out and move on, any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Well where exactly is the exception coming from? What do you mean by "it tells me"?

Comment: When asking about errors exposed by exceptions, please provide full stack trace, not only error message.

Comment: I tried to execute main via BlueJ and when I was prompted to enter parameters, ({ }) I was given the error. I don't know where can I find the "full stack trace".